# Able to write/read file but unable to delete file SWIFT

Tags: swift, directory, delete-file, nsfilemanager

I store an .jpg image i  the iOS documents directory. I can write files and read files but when it comes to deleting them it says that there is no such file but that cannot be because I can read it with the same url.

Reading:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0] as String)
let fullPath = path.appendingPathComponent(info["pi"] as! String)

let data = NSData(contentsOf: fullPath!)
```

Deleting:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
fileManager.delegate = self
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0] as String)
let fullPath = path.appendingPathComponent(info["pi"] as! String)

            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: "\(fullPath!)")
            } catch {
                print("\(error)")
            }
```

It throws:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“image_496251232.806566.jpg” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1758eb40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}, NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/269ADA58-6B09-4844-9FAA-AC2407C1D991/Documents/image_496251232.806566.jpg, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
)}
```

Comment: print fullPath pls

Comment: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/269ADA58-6B09-4844-9FAA-AC2407C1D991/Documents/image_496251232.806566.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `fullPath` variable is a (optional) `URL`. To convert that to a file path string, use the `.path` property, not string interpolation:

```
fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fullPath!.path)
```

Or better, use the URL directly without converting it to a path:

```
fileManager.removeItem(at: fullPath!)
```

(And get rid of the forced unwrapping in favor of option binding ... :-)

Comment: do you know what the objective c equivalent would be?