# Why does not copy database.db from bundle to document directory in swift 3?

Tags: ios, database, swift, copy

I try to copy my db from bundle path to destination path(document directory) and use this code in **iOS8** , **Swift3** and **Xcode8 final**:

```
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cry", ofType: ".db")
    print(bundlePath, "\n") //prints the correct path
    let destPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let fullDestPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath).appendingPathComponent("cry.db")
    let fullDestPathString = String(describing: fullDestPath)
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullDestPathString){
        print("Database file is exist")
        print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bundlePath!))
    }else{
        do{
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: fullDestPathString)
        }catch{
            print("\n")
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

But show me this **error**:

```
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

i have checked *atPath* and *toPath* that's right but i don't have any idea...
Please help me
Thank you

Comment: Same error as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659939/able-to-write-read-file-but-unable-to-delete-file-swift. Use `.path` to convert a URL to a String, not `String(describing:)`.

Comment: atPath and toPath are String values. @MartinR

Comment: Yes, I know. This is wrong `let fullDestPathString = String(describing: fullDestPath)` and should be `let fullDestPathString = fullDestPath.path`

Comment: Yes you are in right.

Answer (score 8):

**Solved**

```
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cry", ofType: ".db")
    let destPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let fullDestPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath).appendingPathComponent("cry.db")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullDestPath.path){
        print("Database file is exist")
        print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bundlePath!))
    }else{
        do{
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: fullDestPath.path)
        }catch{
            print("\n",error)
        }
    }
```

I added *.path* to my destination address and it works now.

Comment: thnk u you solved my problem..

Comment: Thank you so much, it still works just little change in first line '.db' to remove dot in front of ward.